# Why does integer automatically convert to complex?

Tags: python, python-3.x

While experimenting with `complex` types in Python (specifically version 3.6.2 if that changes anything), I made this example:

```
import math

def distance(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    return math.sqrt((x1 - x2) ** 2 + (y1 - y2) ** 2)

def cdistance(z1, z2):
    return distance(z1.real, z1.imag, z2.real, z2.imag)

print('Points:', distance(0, 0, 1, 1))
print('Complex:', cdistance(0, 1+1j)) # <-- Weird Behaivour
```

As expected by a human, it outputs:

```
Points: 1.4142135623730951
Complex: 1.4142135623730951
```

But by a computer, it is odd that Python treats the `0` on the marked line as a complex number though it is passed as an integer.

My question is why the `0` passed to the `cdistance` function on the marked line automatically converted to a `complex` type for use in the function, even though the `cdistance` function refers to the `real` and `imag` fields of the parameter, which is supposedly an integer, not a complex number. What is going on behind the scenes that does this conversion, even when it seems unlikely to do so?

Comment: Any number in python, integer or floating point, has attributes `.imag` and `.real`. This makes sense, because any real number is a complex number with the 0 imaginary part.

Comment: @Julien Numeric literals do not have attributes. `a=0; a.real`

Comment: @Julien, try `(0).real` instead.

Comment: @TimPeters Wow... what is the difference between `0` and `(0)`???

Comment: @Julien, the only difference is syntax.  `0.real` is a syntax error, because the prefix `0.` looks like the _start_ of a float literal, a digit followed by a period.  Only digits can follow it then.  `(0).real` merely avoids the syntax error by inserting parentheses to avoid the ambiguity over what `.` is intended to mean.

Comment: gah stupid me! :) deleting comment above

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Python 3, no conversion at all is happening:  the `int` and `float` types implement `.real` and `.imag` properties directly:

```
>>> zero = 0
>>> zero.real
0
>>> zero.imag
0

>>> fzero = 0.0
>>> fzero.real
0.0
>>> fzero.imag
0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

As **Tim Peters** said int and float implement `.real` and `.imag`

You can verify by using:

```
number = 0
dir(number)
```